# How to deal with JSON response with same key "Value" its String and Array with Retrofit

Tags: java, android, json, performance, retrofit2

In JSON Response there is key "Value" but its response have multiple forms like String and Array with same key "Value".

So how to make Retrofit model class to maintain String and Array with same key "Value".

```
    {
    "RespCode":"SUCCESS",
    "RespText":"Transaction Details",
       "Data":{
              "Record":[
               {
                  "group_title":"Seller Information",
                  "group_values":[
                   {
                        "key":"Listing Agent",
                        "value":[
                            {
                               "key":"Agent First Name",
                               "value":"Myks"
                            },
                            {
                                "key":"Agent Last Name",
                                "value":"Joe"
                            },
                            {
                                "key":"Company",
                                "value":"bdfjdlfdf"
                            },
                            {
                                "key":"Phone",
                                "value":"712.336.4967"
                            },
                            {
                                "key":"Email",
                                "value":"abc@gmail.com"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "key":"Cell Phone",
                        "value":"012.345.6789"
                    },
                    {
                        "key":"Email",
                        "value":"balt@gmail.com.com"
                    },
                    {
                        "key":"Preferred Contact Method",
                        "value":"Phone"
                    }
                ]
            },
   ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use an arraylist that contains multiple hashmaps maybe? Or... You have to define a pojo that has list of arrays with type map or something to that effect

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
public  class ModelBean {

    private String RespCode;
    private String RespText;
    private DataBean Data;

    public String getRespCode() {
        return RespCode;
    }

    public void setRespCode(String RespCode) {
        this.RespCode = RespCode;
    }

    public String getRespText() {
        return RespText;
    }

    public void setRespText(String RespText) {
        this.RespText = RespText;
    }

    public DataBean getData() {
        return Data;
    }

    public void setData(DataBean Data) {
        this.Data = Data;
    }

    public static class DataBean {
        private List<RecordBean> Record;

        public List<RecordBean> getRecord() {
            return Record;
        }

        public void setRecord(List<RecordBean> Record) {
            this.Record = Record;
        }

        public static class RecordBean {
            private String group_title;
            private List<GroupValuesBean> group_values;

            public String getGroup_title() {
                return group_title;
            }

            public void setGroup_title(String group_title) {
                this.group_title = group_title;
            }

            public List<GroupValuesBean> getGroup_values() {
                return group_values;
            }

            public void setGroup_values(List<GroupValuesBean> group_values) {
                this.group_values = group_values;
            }

            public static class GroupValuesBean {
                private String key;
                private List<ValueBean> value;

                public String getKey() {
                    return key;
                }

                public void setKey(String key) {
                    this.key = key;
                }

                public List<ValueBean> getValue() {
                    return value;
                }

                public void setValue(List<ValueBean> value) {
                    this.value = value;
                }

                public static class ValueBean {
                    private String key;
                    private String value;

                    public String getKey() {
                        return key;
                    }

                    public void setKey(String key) {
                        this.key = key;
                    }

                    public String getValue() {
                        return value;
                    }

                    public void setValue(String value) {
                        this.value = value;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried with your solution but throws same error to me. Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 439 path $.Data.Record[1].group_values[0].value

Comment: So basically in response have same key "Value" with String also and Array also. that's why Its throws this error. So please help me with this.